# What is the wrong with the simple ANTLR grammar?

Tags: antlr

I am writing an ANTLR grammar to parse a log files, and faced a problem.
I have simplified my grammar to reproduce the problem as followed:

```
stmt1:
  '[ ' elapse ': ' stmt2
  ;

stmt2:
  '[xxx'
  ;

stmt3:
  ': [yyy'
  ;

elapse :
  FLOAT;

FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* 
    ;
```

When I used the following string  to test the grammar:

```
[ 98.9: [xxx
```

I got the error:

```
E:\work\antlr\output\__Test___input.txt line 1:9 mismatched character 'x' expecting 'y'
E:\work\antlr\output\__Test___input.txt line 1:10 no viable alternative at character 'x'
E:\work\antlr\output\__Test___input.txt line 1:11 no viable alternative at character 'x'
E:\work\antlr\output\__Test___input.txt line 1:12 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ': '
```

But if I remove the ruel 'stmt3', same string would be accepted.

I am not sure what happened...

Thanks for any advice!

Leon

---

Thanks help from Bart. I have tried to correct the grammar.
I think, the baseline, I have to disambiguate all tokens.
And I add WS token to simplify the rule.

```
stmt1:
  '[' elapse ':' stmt2
  ;

stmt2:
  '[' 'xxx'
  ;

stmt3:
  ':' '[' 'yyy'
  ;

elapse :
  FLOAT;

FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* 
    ;

WS : (' ' |'\t' |'\n' |'\r' )+ {skip();} ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANTLR has a strict separation between lexer rules (tokens) and parser rules. Although you defined some literals inside parser rules, they are still tokens. This means the following grammar is equivalent (in practice) to your example grammar:

```
stmt1  : T1 elapse T2 stmt2 ;
stmt2  : T3 ;
stmt3  : T4 ;
elapse : FLOAT;

T1     : '[ ' ;
T2     : ': ' ;
T3     : '[xxx' ;
T4     : ': [yyy' ;
FLOAT  : ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* ;
```

Now, when the lexer tries to construct tokens from the input `"[ 98.9: [xxx"`, it successfully creates the tokens `T1` and `FLOAT`, but when it *sees* `": ["`, it tries to construct a `T4` token. But when the next char in the stream is a `"x"` instead of a `"y"`, the lexer tries to construct another token that starts with `": ["`. But since there is no such token, the lexer emit the error:

> [...] mismatched character 'x' expecting 'y'

And no, the lexer will not backtrack to "give up" the character `"["` from `": ["` to match the token `T2`, nor will it look ahead in the char-stream to see if a `T4` token can really be constructed. ANTLR's LL(*) is only applicable to parser rules, not lexer rules!

Comment: +1 good explanationa although you may have added how to fix it.

Comment: @AndersK, thank you. And it is a bit hard to recommend a fix for a grammar that does not reflect the OP's real grammar. I'm assuming the OP can fix the problem in his actual grammar. And if not, he is free to post it here on SO, of course.

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the detail explanation. It is really useful! Since, as you can see, I am new to ANTLR. Although I have read some tutorial, but I don't know sure how to avoid the problem, and what does OP/SO mean. Could you suggest any useful article to solve the problem? or provide general coding rules to avoid the problem?

Comment: @LeonChen, if you want help with your actual grammar, you'll need to post it (in here, or in a new question). And *OP* means *Original Poster* and *SO* means *stackoverflow*.